# How to create stored proc interaction diagram using Enterprise Architect

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, uml, enterprise-architect

I am analyzing complex stored procedures written for legacy application. In order to understand the flow of calls between stored procs and functions for a given functionality, I would like to create a diagram (similar to Sequence Diagram) using Enterprise Architect.

Does anyone knows what type of diagram is most suitable as I am unable to find the right fit.

I tried Design>Model Patterns>Database>Oracle but cant find shapes to represent interaction between stored procs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn on the DatabaseEngineering MDG you can create a table. There you find constraints as analogy to operations. Once you open them you can define triggers

[image]

[image]

To show the dynamic part it's best to use a sequence diagram showing triggers and execution of stored procedures as messages.

[image]